# Is it possible to constrain function arguments to a predefined type through a mapped type?

Tags: typescript, mapped-types

I am trying to extend some functionality of Redux (think similar to toolkit), and have hit a snag.
From what I understand of the issue it has to do with covaraince/contravariance, but that subject is so alien to my brain that is sort of understand it, but have no clue how to get around it, or if it is even possible.

I am having issues with constraining the type of function the user is able to create as a Selector.
Well.... that is not entirely true, the constraint is actually there and works (more on that later), the issue is, more precisely making the TSC pickup on the information on WHAT is the function's argument to allow for inteliSense to work as intended.

Lets look at our types:

```js
type Selector<S> = (state: S) => any

type SelectorsConstraintMap<Selectors, S> = { [I in keyof Selectors]: Selector<S> }

type Initializer = <State extends object, Selectors extends SelectorsConstraintMap<Selectors, State>>(content: {
    state: State,
    selectors: Selectors
}) => void

declare const init: Initializer

init({
    state: {
        x: 123,
        y: 456
    },
    selectors: {
        // How to make it so that "state" here is of the type we want
        foo: (state) => "foo"
    }
})
```

Now, I know that the function actually is constrained, because if we were to change `foo` to be defined as bellow, we would get an error

```js
    // Type '{ x: number; y: number; }' is not assignable to type 'number'.
foo: (state: number) => "foo"
```

the problem is, `{ x: number; y: number }` is in fact assignable to `any` and if we don't define the state, state is `any` so everything is okay and we do not get any intelliSense when attempting to access properties of `state`.

When I change the `SelectorsConstraintMap` to be a `Record<string, Selector<S>` everything works fine, which leads me to believe that the problem occurs due to a **MAPPED TYPE**, as it probably loses some information there, or mapping somehow allows more than the record does.

Problem is, I need this to be a mapped type because I also need to "enforce" a certain naming convention, namely, selectors have to have a name that conforms to the `selectCapitalCase` pattern.

Comment: What is the "`selectCapitalCase`" pattern?  Does that mean something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WvQgRm)?  I mean, is this an XY problem where you're asking about mapped types but you actually care about the naming convention of the keys?  Or do you really want to make it work with mapped types?

Comment: The naming convetion is a constraint within which I have to work, which is why I mentioned it, in order to avoid andswers such as "use `Record<string, Selector<S>>`". I would love to see this done with a mapped type, because there is more constraints not just the name convention, there are conditionals in the `SelectorsConstraintMap` which constrain stuff further but I ommitted them to make this as short and clean as possible. 

If you think it would be beneficial, I can post all the types exactly as they are in my code.

Comment: If "all the types" is huge then it probably wouldn't be helpful.  Could you find a toy example where `Record<string,...` wouldn't be sufficient?  That is, add just enough to motivate the mapped type without a sidebar about a use case we're not going to explore here?

Comment: I will try to cook it up, give me a moment.

Comment: Okay i think https://tsplay.dev/m0VEaw this is the minimum required to reproduce the issue I have. The mapped type herein is used to produce a custom error message - you might remember us discussing that particular case earlier (though the more I am working with it, the more this presents an issue - I want to ask one more question based on the same types related to that, but I know you do not like 2 in 1 questions so, lets first deal with this)

Comment: Hmm, does that complex type do something more than ensuring `\`select${Capitalize<string>}\``?  I guess it doesn't matter too much, but I was hoping for a smaller example that motivates the mapped type that doesn't digress into how to deal with key name constraints.  I'll just assume you need the mapped type. Anyway, does [this](https://tsplay.dev/wEYLkw) meet your needs? If so then I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what's the issue?

Comment: The mapped type MAY (and i have no clue if this is the case) be necessary to preserve the information because we are dealing with an aggregation of a tuple of same object shapes, however i am not 100% sure it matters. Either way the solution you proposed solves the issue. You can write up an answer and then I will ask the followup question regarding your answer in it's comments? Or do you want me to ask now before you write?

Comment: If by "followup question" you mean that it will not affect the answer to this question, then I'd rather not hear it in comments at all, but posted as a new question.  If, however, it's a clarifying question that could alter the answer here, then it should probably be part of the current post.  Which is it?

Comment: It is mostly dealing with what is the result of creating an intersection between my SelectorsConstraintMap and a Record you suggested do with regards to the rest of the system. I ask this because the `selectorsConstraintMap`, as presented is probably not something I want to propagate through the rest of the types, but instead it only should serve to "block" the argument object passed to initializer from having bad keys. Problem is, those exact keys need to be mapped to the functions return (in this case the `Bundle`) and I am worried the type will bleed through further

Comment: I think you might see that as unrelated, just post the answer in context of our previous discussion, I will open the new question, hopefully it will make more sense then

Comment: I think if you care about that you can, inside your implementation of `init`, widen the  `selectors` property to the `Selectors` type without the intersection. I don't see the intersection in the output of `init()` though, so I think it shouldn't affect things too much.  Yeah, if we want to explore this more it should probably be a new question post.

Comment: Alright, I will make a new question for it, but will need some time to do so, in the mean time, I am eagerly awaiting your answer here so I can read through it. The example given works fine, and as always, thanks for all the help. How would I widen it? By mapping over keys again and just assigning selectors? Actually, I will ask that in the next question. Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript has a hard time in general when asked to infer [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type arguments and callback parameter types [contextually](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html#contextual-typing).  There's an open issue at [microsoft/TypeScript#47599](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47599) asking for improvement, and in fact TypeScript has been steadily getting better at this, but there are always going to be cases where you can't get both to happen at the same time.

In this instance, it seems that having the mapped type in [the constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) blocks contextual inference.  I'll take you at your word that you can't just widen the constraint to `Record<string, Selector<State>>`, and that you need the mapped type to stay.

Luckily it seems that you can give `selectors` a type that's the [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) of the generic type parameter `Selectors` and the wider `Record<string, Selector<State>>` constraint which you know works for inference:

```
type Initializer =
  <State extends object, Selectors extends SelectorsConstraintMap<Selectors, State>>(
    content: {
      state: State,
      selectors: Selectors & Record<string, Selector<State>>
    }
  ) => void
```

This allows `Selectors` to still be inferred as the type of whatever is passed in as `selectors`, but it also gives the methods of `selectors` the context necessary for their parameters to be inferred:

```
init({
  state: {
    x: 123,
    y: 456
  },
  selectors: {
    foo: state => state.x // okay
    //   ^? (parameter) state: { x: number; y: number; }
  }
})
```

That looks good.  Again, note that this does not change the type inferred for `Selectors`, so any other types that depend on `Selectors` should work the same as before; you don't have to try to disentangle the intersection from things, at least not in the type system.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAyhA2EDGwD2AnAPDAfFAvFABQDOwAhsBAFywCUBe5AdiAFBuiSwLJrokAwqmZl05AJbNgAWXJhsvFBhIAaWHkIBvKAG0AklClQA1hBCoAZj0TKBAXVpxb-bHgC+HLtH3MJwCXJ4CQAvCHQCNigobAoqKAgADypmABMSKFQAIwArPnVnPhUE5Ig0jMK7IRExSWk5BUr+NVg4iBwcIijoqCQRFOBaLW6eqDJKGlaJ1RGekiVmpwXigDIoACVkDFTMMSkAcwLlrBg2jtnPaIZ8PAA3VAlUjlTkeHJ0aD7RYCM-QahfP5AsEwugOFJ-ERhtFxlQhrNErQAIwAJgAzDNRiBaAAWACsADZuu5MWNjiR4aNLKhULRYdAbmM2gA6RJQAD07MyJnI7FGnJ6AD0APzEMDvcgAWwgVHQDHpQygiKgzAArpKsuEANxQbEq9Wa9A6y5QTzuOhAA)